# Trying to make new register connection in kafka magic tool on window 11

Tags: apache-kafka, librdkafka

```
Failed connecting to the cluster: Local: Broker transport failure.
%3|1683023665.217|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-4| [thrd:Kafka:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1683023665.217|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-4| [thrd:app]: rdkafka#producer-4: Kafka:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'Kafka:9092': No such host is known.  (after 2674ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1683023668.932|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-4| [thrd:Kafka:9092/bootstrap]: Kafka:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'Kafka:9092': No such host is known.  (after 2701ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
```

Trying for making a new register connection,
but when ever I verify, it shows me error

Comment: As the error says, `Kafka` DNS name doesn't exist. Prove to us that it does by sharing how you're running Kafka, and include the code that shows this exception. Refer [help]  and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Kafka Magic in a local Docker container and trying to connect to another container, then you’ll need to deal with the container networking configuration.
This is not specific to Kafka Magic, it’s a general Docker configuration.

For example, take a look at this article: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-connect-to-localhost-within-a-docker-container/